# Increment UISlider by .1 in range -1.0 to 1.0

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I have found multiple ways to set a sliders value based on ints but I need to increment according to a float .1.

```
float value = [_xSlider value] *.1;
[_xSlider setValue: value/.1];
```

But I get a large float number not just 0.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

I needed to put the number of decimal places I wanted in front of the decimal then act like it was an int, then push the numbers back onto the other side of the decimal.

```
int value = [_xSlider value] * 10;
[_xSlider setValue: value * .1];
```